# How Big a Conference?

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the least number of people that should attend a conference so that there are 3 mutual friends and 3 mutual strangers?

I know this is not hard but I saw somewhere that it should be 6, but I was arguing that it should be 5 since we if there are 3 people that know one another and another 2 that are complete strangers we can take one from the 3 friends to make 3 mutual strangers. Is my argument correct?

Comment: There's no number that will guarantee 3 mutual friends *and* 3 strangers; however many there are, they could all be friends, or all strangers.  The usual phrasing of this question is how many people are needed to guarantee 3 mutual friends *or* 3 strangers, and the answer is indeed 6.  You can read about [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem).

Comment: Search the web for "six people at a party"

Comment: Though if you have four people in total, with three being mutual friends, there cannot be three mutual strangers.  You cannot say that with five people in total with three being mutual friends